# MS Word drawing canvas equivalent in Powerpoint

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-powerpoint, canvas

Is there a "Drawing canvas" (from MS Word) equivalent in MS Powerpoint?
I like the fact I can add shapes and images in a specific area and move them all together easily.
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there's no equivalent in PPT; instead, you could select then group all of the shapes you want to move together.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create a Drawing Canvas in MS Word then copy/paste into MS PowerPoint. However, as [Steve Rindsberg answered](https://superuser.com/questions/1594898/ms-word-drawing-canvas-equivalent-in-powerpoint#answer-1595682), there does not appear to be native support for creating these in MS PowerPoint. However, the editing experience is not ideal / equivalent. For example, I can move/edit shapes on the canvas, but I can't seem to create new ones in there while in MS PowerPoint -- instead have to do it all in MS Word then copy back, which is cumbersome.